# C / C++ program connecting to 32-bit DB2 and 64-bit DB2 simultaneously

Tags: c, unix, 64-bit, db2, 32-bit

Is it possible to successfully author a C / C++ program in *IX operating systems that operates on both 32-bit and 64-bit DB2 implementations simultaneously?

The exact requirement is to read from a 32-bit DB2 database and write into a 64-bit DB2 database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the C Common Client uses a network connection, there's no obvious reason why the 32-bit client should not connect to either a 32-bit or a 64-bit server (or both on separate connections).  The same comment applies to 64-bit clients.  The DRDA protocol used to communicate between client and server should be OK.

I can answer definitively for Informix (which you didn't ask about) - I use 32-bit or 64-bit ESQL/C to connect to either 32-bit or 64-bit IDS servers without problem.  The only limitation is on a shared memory connection; then the client and server must be of the same 'bittiness'.  But the network connections and the local (stream, socket) connections are neutral.

Comment: Sometimes I wish I could accept answers to questions that aren't mine.  This would get one such check-mark.  The same answer applies to DB2.

Comment: @Tanktalus: thanks for confirmation that my answer applies to DB2 too.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is, that you have to load both libraries simultaneously. You can't just link both in the executable using two -l options, because the symbol names collide. If this is the problem, dlopen if your friend.

```
#include <dlfcn.h>

void * handle=dlopen(filename,RTLD_NOW|RTLD_GLOBAL);

bool (*some_function)(char * name);
some_function=(bool (*)(char *))dlsym(handle,"name_of_some_function");
if (some_function("test")) {
    ....
} else {
    ....
}
```

Because I don't know DB2 I can't help you any further, but if this was the problem, you should now have everything to solve the problem.